# Using glob and wildcards to open a file

Tags: python, glob, geopandas

I am trying to read a group of files from a folder using glob and wildcards, however python won't read_file from my directory.
My code looks like this:

```
from glob import glob
import geopandas as gpd

extent_dir = glob( '/Users/extents' + '/extent_' + '*.shp' ) 
extent = gpd.read_file(extent_dir)
```

I need to use the wild card as I will be adding files with idfferent names. the file name looks something like this : *extent_1234354.shp*

Comment: `glob.glob()` returns a list of filenames matching the pattern you specify. `read_file` expects one filename, not the full list.

Comment: Also: `"a constant string plus " + "another constant string" == "a string plus another constant string"`, no need for the arithmetics in the call to `glob`, just put the string as a whole (and for string with parameters, use `.format()` for f-strings)

Comment: thanks! got it to work using os.path.join